# How does karma protect everyone?

Tags: karma

I have doubt regarding karma.
Let me explain my doubt with example.

Today a beggar's fate was to get only one rupee but with my freewill I am giving him 4 rupees extra money. What I gave  added as punyam in my account.

On the next day, beggar's fate was to experience one beatings in stomach with my freewill I am giving him two beatings the extra beatings I gave is added as a papa in my account.

So, if I can do extra papa to other which is not in their fate means that they can experience pain that which is not in their fate. So how karma protects every one?

Please explain with example.

Comment: Most of us here imagine a lot about Karmas, Isvara, Parabrahman, fate, destiny etc... See Karma is different from destiny, and fate. Secondly Karma doesnt protect, - situation can turn upside down in no time with respect to Karma but its Dharma which protects those who protect Dharma..

Comment: Dharma is also a punya karma

Comment: Dharma if I'm not wrong doesnt go into accounts of Karma. If a beggar asks something for food from me, and if I give, that action doesnt have any calculation. ....If you're asking about Karma protection, then Karna could be an example!!! but that too didnt last long as he also finally gave his all good karmas and after that he was defeated!!

Comment: If the beggar eventually received 4rs then how can you say that it was his fate to receive only 1rs? @harishandroid

Comment: What you hv done to the beggar was both in his and in yours fate .. If you think in this way there is no confusion @harishandroid

Comment: The Q is clear but his assumption is wrong .. He says "the beggar's fate has only 4rs but I gave him 1rs" but that's not true, if the beggar received 4rs then that it was in his fate to receive that much amount of money only @Pratimaputra

Answer (score 2):

Karma doesn't protect you, karma is just something you get to enjoy or suffer. We do not know what is one's fate, so we cannot assume his fate is to get 1 rupee only. If you gave him 4 rupees extra money, it means his fate was to get 1+4 or that is to say 5.

Karma doesn't protect you, only the Lord can protect you if you take shelter in the Lord as per the example in the Bhagavad-gita where Lord Krishna says we can take protection in Him, see verse 18.66 (translation from vedabase):

> Abandon all varieties of religion and **just surrender unto Me. I shall deliver you from all sinful reactions. Do not fear.**

So if we take protection in Lord Krishna, ie if we take refuge in Him, or that is to say if we surrender to Him, He will take care for us, He will protect us from our bad fate and thus we will not suffer bad karma, ie sinful karma (papa).

Answer (score 1):

Who said or what scripture/source says Karma protects? Scriptures instead says Karma binds or liberates based on nature of such karma. Nothing to do with protection.

Bhagavad Gita Chapter 3, Verse 9 says -

*yajnarthAt karmano-nyatra
lokOyam karma-bandhanAh
tadArtham karma kauntEya
mukta-sangAh samAcara*

Meaning: Work done should be done as a as a sacrifice for God, otherwise work binds one to this material world. Therefore, O son of Kunti, perform your prescribed duties for God's satisfaction, and in that way you will always remain unattached and free from bondage.

Regarding your actions in your example, Bhagavad Gita  Chapter 3, verse 5 says -

*nahi kaschchit kṣhaṇam api jAtu tiṣhṭhatyakarma-kṛit
kAryate hyavaschaḥ karma sarvAḥ prakṛitIjair guṇaiḥ*

Meaning: All men are forced to act helplessly according to the impulses born of the modes of material nature; therefore no one can refrain from doing something, not even for a moment.